# Jenkins build job cannot locate item in a keychain

Tags: android, macos, security, jenkins, keychain

I've got a jenkins job that will execute a gradle script that retrieves android store and key passwords from the keychain. The script works fine running on my local machine, however I'm trying to add it to the jenkins job and it's failing to locate the item in the keychain:

`security: SecKeychainSearchCopyNext: The specified item could not be found in the keychain.`

The command it's trying to run is: `security -q find-generic-password -a jenkins -gl storePassword`

Running this command from terminal retrieves the password as expected.

I think the problem is to do with the fact that jenkins job is running under jenkins user. I've tried su to jenkins user and I think it only has system keychain - if I do `security list-keychains` it comes up with `System.keychain`. My store and key passwords are inside login keychain which I don't think jenkins user has access to? Any suggestions how to rectify this? I've tried creating the keychain through security but that didn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is useful for someone:

1) Create a new keychain using keychain-access. Let's call it 'jenkins', for example.
2) Copy the keychain to the `jenkins` library directory (`$HOME/Library/Keychains/jenkins.keychain`)
3) run `chown jenkins:jenkins` on the `jenkins.keychain`
4) run `sudo su jenkins` to switch to jenkins user.
5) add the jenkins.keychain to the keychain list `security list-keychains -s ~/Library/Keychains/jenkins.keychain`
6) add a bash script call to the jenkins build process to unlock the keychain. ideally, the call should use the password stored in the jenkins build via the mask password plugin. Something like `security unlock-keychain -p "${jenkins_keychain_password}" "$HOME/Library/Keychains/jenkins.keychain"`

This is a good guide for more details: http://www.egeek.me/2015/04/12/jenkins-setting-up-ios-code-signing/